# How to add parameter to rails index action/method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameter-passing, rails-routing

I want to pass a parameter to the index action, but the I'm only getting the show action.

routes.rb:

```
Test1::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :blog
end
```

blog_controller.rb:

```
  def show
    # code
  end

  def index
    # code
  end
```

View url that send to show action instead to index action:

```
<a  href="/blog/myvar">  My link </a>
```

What should I add in routes file or in view?

Output of my routes:

```
$ rake routes

blog GET    /blog(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"blog"}

blog GET    /blog/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"blog"}
```

Comment: not sure if i understand.  you want to pass a parameter to the index action?

Comment: yes to index action, if you have other way please write

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command line will show you routes you can use with `rake routes`

The route you want is `blogs_path` and you can add a parameter on to that, e.g. `blogs_path(other_item => :value)`.

Exactly how will depend on whether you are try to use it in a controller, another view, etc.

For the view have: `<%= link_to 'My Link', blogs_path(:other_item => value) %>`

Comment: please see my routes output in edit. I try to do blogs_path('myparam' => :value) but it takes to show action

Comment: i get this routes also, but i bring only my 2 routes that i have problem with them

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want 2 routes:

```
/blogs/:other_param
/blogs/:id
```

But, for as smart as Rails is, it can't figure out whether the param is meant to be treated as an other_param or as an id.

So the simplest solution is to add this route to the resources defaults like so:

```
resources :blogs
get "/blogs/other_param/:other_param", to: "blogs#index", as: "other_param_blogs"
```

That way Rails knows that if you're going to /blogs/other_param/current, then it will treat current as the :other_param.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to pass parameter:

```
<a href="/blog?name=test">My link </a>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "My link", blog_path(name: "test") %>
```

above code will redirect to index action with name as key and test as parameter,